# keeping track of the removed indices of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i have a form with text box and checkbox. When i fill value to the checkbox , the value is pushed into an array.When I unchecked the checkbox, the value is removed from that array.
Here is my working [code pen.](http://codepen.io/surajkhanal/pen/PbPGgJ?editors=1011)

This is my form code

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="In a word, what is important to you?" ng-model="values.first" >
    <ion-checkbox ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.first,values.first)"  ng-change="show2='true'" ng-model="success.first"  
           ng-disabled="!values.first" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;" class="checkbox-royal"></ion-checkbox>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-input" ng-show="show2" ng-class="{'animated-custom slideInLeft':success.first}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What else is important to you?" ng-model="values.second" >

    <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.second" ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.second,values.second)" ng-change="show3='true'" ng-disabled="!values.second" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-input" ng-show="show3" ng-class="{'animated-custom slideInLeft':success.second}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What else is important to you?" ng-model="values.third">

    <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.third" ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.third,values.third)" ng-change="show4='true'" ng-disabled="!values.third" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-input" ng-show="show4" ng-class="{'animated-custom slideInLeft':success.third}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What else is important to you?" ng-model="values.four">

    <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.four" ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.four,values.four)" ng-change="show5='true'" ng-disabled="!values.four" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
  </label>
```

And this is controller code ,

```
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
  var values=[];
  $scope.toggleCheckBox=function(isChecked, value){
    if(isChecked){
      values.push(value);
      console.log(values);
    }else{
      var currentIndex = values.indexOf(value);
      values.splice(currentIndex, 1);
      console.log(values);
       //console.log(values.indexOf(value));
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is, when i remove the value from array and again check the checkbox, it pushes the value to last . Is it possible to retain the original position of that value in the array?

Comment: Is the number of text box controls fixed to a max of 4 or can it go beyond that as per the end users' wish?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the item index in `toggleCheckBox` and set the value of the array item depending on the passed index and the values you want like:

```
var x = Array();
var index = 2;
x[index] = 'A';
console.log(x);
```

But make sure when you want to use the array to iterate over it and splice the items with `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1):

Add a third parameter to `toggleCheckBox` with the position - something like:

```
...
<ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.four" ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.four,values.four,4)"
...
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
  var values=[];
  $scope.toggleCheckBox=function(isChecked, value, pos){
    if(isChecked){
      values[pos] = value;
    }else{
      values[pos] = null;
    }
    console.log(values);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can add a value to a specific index in an array:

```
let arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
arr[3] = 'baz'; // 0 and 1 are taken
console.log(arr); //=> ['foo', 'bar', undefined, 'baz']
```

This is not recommended however. In JavaScript, arrays are  numbered indexes and trying to work around this behaviour will likely become problematic very soon.

What you need instead is an object. If you name your inputs:

```
<input name="some_checkbox_1">
```

...and use those names to create an object:

```
$scope.toggleCheckBox=function(isChecked, value){
    values[this.name] = isChecked;
}
```

Which results in an object like this:

```
{ some_checkbox_1: true, some_checkbox_2: false } // this is the `values` variable
```

If you then want to get an array out of this object with the true and/or false values, use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(values); //=> [true, false]
```

This way, you can render your checkboxes in sequence and set them to `checked` based on the true/false values of your stored object. Hope this helps.

*Note: in the code above I assume that `this` refers to the checkbox’s HTML element*

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript Object properties order never change**

So, you can create an Object to maintain the order and iterate over the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to fill the array `values` based on the `value` or `false` accordangly:

```
angular
  .module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
    var values = [],
        obj = {};

    $scope.toggleCheckBox = function (isChecked, value, index) {
        values = []; // Clean the values
        obj[index] = (isChecked) ? value : false;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
            obj[k] && values.push(obj[k]); // Fill the ordered values
        });

        console.clear();
        console.log(values);
    };
  });
```

In the veiew, I have added an `index` for all the checkboxes, which is the number of the `ion-checkbox`:

```
<ion-checkbox 
  ng-click="toggleCheckBox(success.first,values.first, 1)"  
  ng-change="show2='true'" 
  ng-model="success.first"
  ng-disabled="!values.first" 
  style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"
  class="checkbox-royal">
</ion-checkbox>
```

Check the complete solution at [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/yosvelquintero/pen/QGEoLx).

Comment: Thanks @Yosvel Quintero

Comment: But if i change the value of the field , it just pushes the value to last index of an array instead of modifying the previous value.

Comment: Your right.. I was not considering the modified values.. working on that..

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that , when the form field contains same value no dublicate value is pushed to an array.

Comment: That is solved in the last solution update.. check please